# SVG problems with Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, firefox, svg

I have been making a simple website with AngularJS and D3JS and created a custom circle mesh library (very crude). It all works fine in Firefox but it doesn't work in Chrome. The website is up at petoknm.github.io . In my homepage I have this circle mesh thing that displays the circles. But when I transition (directly) to another page with this circle mesh (programmming page) it starts behaving differently. And when I go from programming to home it starts to ignore the clipPath on the first two images (two probably because of the two images in the programming page). The svg is identical (I checked only the first three 'a' tags with the images and the first three clipPaths) to the correct svg that was there first... I don't know what happens.

This is a screenshot just after first loading the page

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fAI6.png

This is a screenshot after coming from the programming page

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLO3r.png

As you can see the clipPath is still in the svg and "shown" by Chrome but is not actually used (or is ignored).

Please help, I have no idea why it happens and why it's no problem for Firefox

Comment: Share you code mate.

Comment: http://petoknm.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

I'll make an educated guess and say it's because your programming page is reusing ids "#clippath0" and "#clippath1".  Because it's a single page site and you are replacing the parts of the DOM that contain  those references, perhaps there is a bug in Chrome where it getting confused over what they point to.

Try using different sets of ids for each page and see if that fixes it.  Maybe you could add different prefixes for each page (eg "#homeclippath0" and "#programmingclippath0").

It does seem like a bug in Chrome though.  Perhaps you might want to report it.

Comment: Thank you. Changing the IDs to be always unique helped. But I will try to report the bug.